# How create SVN.EXE file for R in a Windows 10

Tags: ssh, svn, rstudio

I'm trying to generate a SSH RSA key for RStudio, but I don't have SVN.EXE file anywhere in C:.

How can I fix it?

Comment: SVN is a third party program you have to manually download and install. I recommend to install [TortoiseSVN](https://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html) which includes SVN.exe and additionally allows you to manage SVN repositories via Windows Explorer and thus outside of any IDE.

Comment: FYI TortoiseSVN does not install svn.exe and other SVN command line tools by default. You need to select this option in the installer.

Comment: @bahrep can I download from anywhere? Should I install https://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html, so from there choose that option? Is that the way?